# Solution of "internally" coupled Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following differential equation:

$x\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} - (1-x)\cdot\frac{dz}{dx}=0$ given the conditions of $y(x=0)=1$ and $z(x=1)=1$.

I am confused since these are coupled(?) differential equations but normally than I would have two equations? Do I have to split them up?

Comment: What are you being asked for as solution? Maybe $\frac{dz}{dy}$?

Comment: No, I want to have y(x) and z(x).

Comment: I do not think you have enough data to obtain both $y$ and $z$.